# How do I display long results in LFE REPL?

Tags: erlang, lisp, lfe

Following image shows that LFE truncates displayed results. Compared to SBCL REPL I can see less than half of result data.

[image]

How do I show all results in LFE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see it printed in LFE format you can use

```
(lfe_io:format "~p\n" (list (lists:seq 1 50)))
```

or, much easier, in the LFE repl:

```
(pp (lists:seq 1 50))
```

There is also a `(p ...)` call which writes it out without prettyprinting.

Answer (score 1):

Something I do in this case is often to use io:format:

```
io:format("~p~n", [X]).
```

I guess it's the same with LFE, but with slightly different syntax.